# jquery get All from element to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to select all elements from given elements to another given elements?
example:

```
 <div>
    <div>
        <a name="break1"></a>
        <p> belongs to break 1</p>
        <div>
            <p> belongs to break 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>belongs to break 1</p>
    <div>
        <a name="break2"></a>
        <p> belongs to break 2</p>
        <div>
            <p> belongs to break 2</p>
            <div>
                <p> belongs to break 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

we need something like the following:

```
$('[name*="break1"]').selectAllUntil('[name*="break2"]');
```

and result should be:

```
<p> belongs to break 1</p>
<div>
    <p> belongs to break 1</p>
</div>
<p>belongs to break 1</p>
```

Most important thing: need to look down the siblings of each element up to the element matched by the selector, if we didnt find it we need to keep searching at the parent node

this can be misleading because we need to select all until the next element, even though the next element exist in the parent elements

Comment: There is a way to do that, but it would be much easier to just change the html to something that makes more sense.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which element are you referring to?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kt10r6n5/

Comment: What element(s) do you want to select? From which element until which other element? What have you tried?

Comment: we need to refactor an exsist html, we can't change the html

Comment: @MosheBaranes checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the html is always the same you could try using `prevAll()`.

**Example:**

`$('.break2').parent().prevAll().css('color', 'blue');`

https://jsfiddle.net/kt10r6n5/1/

Note:

If you are using a class like you have in your demo then this might be problematic if you have multiple instances of that same class. You would then have to find the last instance of that class. This will work better with an id of course.

**Docs:**

http://api.jquery.com/prevall/

Answer (score 0):

I created method in plunker: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/XUNCkYMJz4TEekLdBrJM?p=preview

This script returns jquery object with collection of elements between selector1 and selector2.

**EDIT**. Ok i got in now! It should work as expected.

**IMPORTANT** - script is working on level of selector parent, so is dependend to html structure.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
 selectAllUntil: function(selector) {

   var currentDiv=this.parent("div");
   var elements = $();//empty jquery collection


   while(currentDiv.length){


     if (currentDiv.find(selector).length){
         //if our element have inside selector then this is end
         return elements;

     }else{
         //no selector so add 
        elements= elements.add(currentDiv);
     }

     //next element
     currentDiv=currentDiv.next();

    }



  }});

//usage:
$(function(){

  var elements=$('[name*="break2"]').selectAllUntil('[name*="break4"]');
  elements.css("color","red");



});
```

Comment: Hi maciej, Thanks for your answer,we dont know if next (the until)element is a sibiling or in parent or descendants of the from element

Comment: It is not what You needed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we dont know if next (the until)element is a sibiling or in parent or descendants of the from element